# Qt. No rule to make target in the '.pro', needed by 'Makefile'. Stop

Tags: c++, qt, makefile, target

So, I wrote a code for a Pythagoras calculator app in Qt creator, but when I try to compile it I get the following error message:

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target '../CalculadoradePitágoras16062022/CalculadoradePitágoras16062022.pro', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.
```

My pro. file looks like this:

```
QT       += core gui                                              
greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets                                          
TARGET = CalculadoradePitágoras16062022                                                
TEMPLATE = app                                                                          
SOURCES += main.cpp\
           widget.cpp                                                                   
HEADERS  += widget.h                                                                      
FORMS    += widget.ui                                                                 
RESOURCES += \
            Resources.qrc                                                              
RC_ICONS = IconoP070720222.ico
```

By the way, I´ve tried to turn off the shadowbuild checkbox but I get another error:

```
:-1: error: No rule to make target '../../../../../../../Qt/Qt5.2.0/5.2.0/mingw48_32/mkspecs/modules/qt_lib_designercomponents_private.pri', needed by 'Makefile'.  Stop.
```

What should I do in this case?

Comment: Why don't you use cmake?

Comment: @LászlóPapp, How?

Comment: What is your directory structure like? On windows that'd be the command "dir /s" from your project folder. On linux it'd be "ls -R" Also, you're using Qt4, which has been unsupported for over 7 years now. The recommendation would be to use Qt6 and cmake. Check the documentation on the Qt website.

Answer (score 0):

I would personally use cmake for any new Qt projects launched, going forward. This is because Qt has chosen cmake to be the buildsystem for Qt.

Whilst in essence, you can use something else, it is still reasonable to remain consistent with that.

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
set(CMAKE_AUTORCC ON)
find_package(Qt5 5.15 REQUIRED COMPONENTS Core Widgets)
add_executable(QtResource Resources.qrc main.cpp widget.cpp)
target_link_libraries(QtResource Qt::Widgets)
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include <QApplication>                                                     
                                                                                
int main(int argc, char *argv[])                                                
{                                                                               
  QApplication app(argc, argv);                                             
  // Do something with the resource.                                            
  return app.exec();                                                            
}
```

**application.qrc**

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/" >
        <file>IconoP070720222.ico</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: excuse me if i ask too much questions but i´m new to Qt and this is the first project i´ve made with it. Where can i find (or paste) the "CMakeLists.txt"?, and where is the "application.qrc"?.